# What is wrong with this conditional function?

Tags: javascript

Alright, so I am following along the DLTP course, so I'm not sure if this syntax is unheard of elsewhere. Basically what I am trying to do is make the image that is 231 pixels wide split into 3 equal columns, one column of red,green,blue tinted. I have no clue what I am doing wrong here. When I call my function, it just prints the original image two times.

When I made this(and tweaked it with research on else/if and for loops), I was thinking that any pixel under 77 along the x axis would get tinted green, then I just repeated that for each color and column I needed.

Any help without flat out typing it correctly would be awesome. I'm trying to understand the concepts, not have a cheat sheet.

```
var img = new SimpleImage("chapel.png");
print(img);

function stripeyPic(img){
  for (var pixel of img.values()){

    if(pixel.getX < 77){
        pixel.setGreen(255);
    }
    else if(pixel.getX > 154){
        pixel.setRed(255);
    }
    else if(pixel.getX <= 78 && pixel.getX >=155){
        pixel.setBlue(255);
    }
  }
  print(img);
}

stripeyPic(img);
```

Comment: I wonder if changing `var pixel` to `let pixel` would help?

Comment: What is "the DLTP course"?

Comment: Without seeing more of the underlying code I can't say for certain, but based on the naming I expect you might want to actually use `getX()` since that sounds like a function name.

Comment: Duke Learn to Program

Comment: John. OMG. I can't believe. I had tried that before and it didn't work but I changed it just now and it worked perfectly. I am so baffled, but thank you so much for getting me to redo that. I probably had bad code, and thought the brackets weren't needed and then after "fixing" the code, didn't put them back.

Comment: The lesson here is to work on your debugging skills: rather than trying to fix the whole program, test each part carefully, using things like `console.log(pixel.getX())` and then _don't touch the parts you've proven are correct_.

Answer (score 2):

Have a careful look at this condition:

```
(pixel.getX <= 78 && pixel.getX >=155)
```

This requires a number that is both lower than 79 and higher than 154, which clearly doesn't exist. What you meant was this:

```
(pixel.getX >= 78 && pixel.getX <=155)
```

But in fact you don't need to state that at all, because you can just use `else` to mean "not matching either of the previous two conditions".

Comment: I tried to do that. So if I delete that entire if condition, the entire picture just gets tinted blue. I only delete "if(pixel.getX <= 78 && pixel.getX >=155)", and the entire picture gets tinted blue. Sorry for repetition but it's hurting my brain because I feel like this should work, and I actually cannot see why it isn't.